# Can someone solve these four simultaneous equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

I am solving a boundary value problem and stuck at simple algebra part. I've four equation as:

1. $E_i+E_r=E_++E_-$
2. $E_i-E_r=n(E_+-E_-)$
3. $E_t=E_+e^{i\phi}+E_-e^{-i\phi}$
4. $n(E_+e^{i\phi}-E_-e^{-i\phi})=E_t$

Here n and $\phi$ are constants. And I am trying to express $E_t$ and $E_r$ in terms of $E_i$ separately.
Any kind of idea will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't, this is an undeterminate system (four equations in five unknows).

Comment: is this from quantum mechanics?

Comment: @tired no it's from electromagnetic theory.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but book says it's possible to solve this.

Comment: would you mind to give some context?

Comment: yes.
I am solving problem 7.5 of 3rd edition Classical electrodynamics by Jackson. A wave is being reflected, transmitted by both sides of a sheet of conductor. Ei, Er, Et, E+ and E- are incident, reflected from left side of sheet, transmitted, moving toward right inside sheet and moving toward left inside sheet waves respectively.
and i applied 4 boundary conditions that gave me 4 equations (given in question). these 4 equations are correct according to a solution available at (http://www-personal.umich.edu/~pran/jackson/P505/hw11a.pdf page#4).

Comment: this solution says Er and Et can be expressed in terms of Ei. but somehow i can't solve it.

Comment: Adding the first two gets rid of $E_r$ and equating the left of 4 to the right of 3 gets rid of $E_t$.  You now have two linear equations in two unknowns if we consider $E_i$ a parameter.  There are a fair number of constants around, so a bit of a mess.

Comment: In fact the OP asks to express $E_t$ and $E_r$ *in terms of one of the other $3$ unknowns*, so you can use $4$ equations in $5$ unknowns to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Use equations 1 and 2 to express $E_+$ and $E_-$ in terms of $E_i, E_r$ and $n$:
$$
E_+ = \frac1{2n} (E_i -E_r + n(E_r + E_i))\\
E_- = \frac1{2n} (E_r -E_i + n(E_r + E_i))
$$
Step 2: Substitute for $E_+$ and $E_-$ in equations 3 and 4:
$$
3: E_t = \frac1{2n} \left( e^{i\phi} (E_r-E_i+n(E_r+E_i))
+ e^{-i\phi} (E_r-E_i-n(E_r+E_i))
\right) 
\\E_t= \frac1n\left[
(n\cos\phi +i\sin\phi)E_i + (n\cos\phi -i\sin\phi)E_r) 
\right]$$
and$$
4:E_t = (\cos\phi + ni\sin\phi)E_i -(\cos\phi -ni\sin\phi)E_r
$$
Step 3: Equate those two expressions for $E_t$ and thus have one equation to solve for $E_r$ in terms of $n,\phi,E_i$:
$$
E_r = -E_i \frac{(n^2-1\sin\phi}{(n^2+1)\sin\phi+2in\cos\phi}
$$
Step 4: substitute $E_r$ into either of the $E_t$ expressions and simplify to get
$$
E_t = E_i\frac{2in}{2in\cos\phi+(n^2+1)\sin\phi}
$$
Don't be scared by the fact that the expressions imply complex values; i fact, in a general medium, the index of reflection $n$ is also complex.

Do be scared by the fact that in the first edition of Jackson, problem 7.5 is different, asking for the transmission coefficient when a plane wave strikes a thin or thick "excellent conductor." If I remember correctly, the solution to that problem is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If $E_i$ is considered known, you have a system of four equations in four unknowns

$$\begin{cases}+E_r&&-E_+&-E_-&=-E_i\\
 -E_r&&-nE_+&+nE_-&=-E_i\\
 &+E_t&-E_+e^{i\phi}&-E_-e^{-i\phi}&=0\\
 &-E_t&+nE_+e^{i\phi}-&nE_-e^{-i\phi}&=0.\end{cases}$$

You can solve it by Cramer or by Gaussian elimination.